# Processing 3 with P3D renderer embedded in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, canvas, processing, renderer

In my current project, I need to embed a **Processing 3** canvas in my **Java Swing** application. I could find some good examples for P2D renderer, which worked perfectly fine; however, my application is using **P3D renderer** for displaying 3D models.

After a thorough search on the Internet and reading the source codes, I could get *a solution*, which *does not work properly*.

Here is a **baby example** of what I have so far followed by the **screenshots of my issue** (the example uses JFrame for simplicity and conciseness).

```
public class Visualiser3D extends PApplet {

    private PeasyCam camera;

    @Override
    public void settings() {
        size(1000, 800, P3D);
    }

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        camera = new PeasyCam(this, 0, 0, 0, 1500);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        camera();        // force default coordsys
        camera.feed();   // manually set peasycam
        background(30);
        sphere(200);    // draw a sphere
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // prepare JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Processing in JFrame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // run Processing
        Visualiser3D mp3d = new Visualiser3D();
        PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{"MyPapplet 3D"}, mp3d);
        PSurfaceJOGL pSurfaceJOGL = (PSurfaceJOGL) mp3d.getSurface();
        pSurfaceJOGL.initOffscreen(mp3d);
        // add canvas to JFrame (used as a Component)
        NewtCanvasAWT canvas = (NewtCanvasAWT) pSurfaceJOGL.getComponent();
        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
        pSurfaceJOGL.startThread();

        // display
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots of what I get. The actual processing window keeps running, and if I close it programmatically, the entire application gets closed. I would like to have the **Processing canvas embedded inside of my Java Swing application** without any other open windows.

[image: JFrame with inserted Processing Canvas]
[image: Processing Window running]

I hope that you will be able to help me do it properly.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to embed your sketch inside a JFrame instead of letting Processing handle the window for you?

Comment: Hi Kevin, as I mentioned I use JFrame in this example for conciseness. I will have an application with a bunch of control panels and I would like to have a Processing canvas embedded inside to make it look like one application. Here is the link with the screenshot example: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2-nAZegCS3WRWJFNklPMkhLZGc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Related/cross-post: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/17351/processing-3-with-p3d-embedded-in-jpanel